# Is there a way to disable a Messages account via command line?

Tags: command-line, messages

I'd like to stop/start receiving SMS/iMessage via command line, to avoid having to go into system preferences.

Is there a way I can manipulate settings for Messages to enable/disable an account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out stopping was more logical than expected:

```
tell application "Messages"
     repeat with s in services
            set n to name of s
            log out s
     end repeat
end tell
```

It doesn't seem to work the other way around. I've tried and I've tried, and I can't get no satisfaction.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know, but here is a list of all MacOS command-line commands: https://ss64.com/osx/

Nothing in this list explicitly answers your question. So I would assume there is not a way to do this from the command-line.

Comment: It might be useful if you read the post [How to Write a Good Answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in our [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/).  I'm refraining from down voting, though I highly suggest taking a second look at this answer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. And, just providing a link isn't very helpful as it may no longer work in future. Instead, could you please edit your answer to include a summary of the *relevant* content from the page you're linking to? This will make your answer more self-contained and help preserve it for other users in future.